# Use spinner's Text for insert

Tags: c#, android

is there any way using spinner's Text and insert it into an sql table.
Or its better using a textview and style it as spinner?
Take a look in my code:

```
Spinner spinner1 = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner1);

con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into customermaster (id,name) values (9,'"+spinner1.Text+ "')", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I get error: Spinner does not contain definition for Text.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for : spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()